# How to put in loop "button.config"

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tkinter

In the process of creating the application, rather cumbersome parts of the code appeared.
I created an example of such sections of code

The main problem is that only "... .config..." should be placed in the loop.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")
root.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")
root.title("TESTING")

button_1=Button(root,text="Click")
button_2=Button(root,text="Click")
button_3=Button(root,text="Click")
button_4=Button(root,text="Click")

#-----------------------------------------------------------
button_1.config(command=lambda: print('Button_1 presed'))
button_2.config(command=lambda: print('Button_2 presed'))
button_3.config(command=lambda: print('Button_3 presed'))
button_4.config(command=lambda: print('Button_4 presed'))
#-----------------------------------------------------------

button_1.pack()
button_2.pack()
button_3.pack()
button_4.pack()

root.mainloop()

#I tested this example, but it didn't work

for i in range(1,4):
    f"button_{i}.config(command=lambda: print('Button_{i} presed'))"
```

Comment: You want your Buttons in a single list, rather than four separate variables - so that you can use a `for` loop to do things with all of the Buttons without having to replicate code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The typo was spotting by @TheLizzard. Is should be `lambda j=j: my_fun(j)`

Try this:

Code:

```
import tkinter  as tk 


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")  
root.title("How to put in loop button.config") 


def my_fun(k):
    print(f'Btn No is : {str(k)}')

n=5 # number of buttons

for j in range(1,n):
    e = tk.Button(root, text=j,command=lambda j=j: my_fun(j)) 
    e.pack(padx=5, pady=j) 
            
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Btw `lambda k=j: my_fun(k)` might be confusing to beginners, and `lambda j=j: my_fun(j)` might be easier to understand.

Comment: @TheLizzard. Thank for spotting typo error. I will updating.